# wrong datetime returned in caml query in c#

Tags: development, caml-query, date-time

I have custom list in sharepoint 2016 on-premises. There are several columns in DateTime type. I need to query this list in C#, but when I run my query I get wrong dates - I get always the day before the date which I see in the list. For ex: I have a column HiringDate in the list and record with value "10/2/2018" (MM/dd/yyyy). The caml query in c# code returns it "2018.10.01. 22:00". Here's my code:

```
            List oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
            ListItemCollection items = oList.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
            FieldCollection fcol = oList.Fields;
            context.Load(items);
            context.Load(fcol);
            context.Load(oList);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            string[,] list = new string[items.Count, 3];

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {

                var itemValue = items[i]["HiringDate"];
                Console.WriteLine(itemValue);
                if(itemValue != null && itemValue.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    list[i, 1] = ((DateTime)itemValue).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
                    Console.WriteLine(list[i, 1]);
                }


            }
```

I am new to c# and sharepoint. Why I receive wrong date and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint store datetime as UTC format, you can convert the datetime to site time zone time with below sample code:

```
var localTime = clientContext.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime((DateTime)_Item.FieldValues["Created"]);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```